# Grabbing all fields when trying to unmarshal nested XML

Tags: xml, go

Here is a bit of the XML file I'm trying to pull into Golang.  The actual XML file is over 500 MB.

```
<artists>
   <artist>
      <id>1</id>
      <name>The Persuader</name>
      <realname>Jesper DahlbÃ¤ck</realname>
      <profile />
   </artist>
    <artist>
       <id>22</id>
       <name>DATacide</name>
       <profile>Datacide began recording together in 1993, after Tetsu Inoue met Uwe Schmidt while vacationing near Frankfurt.
       </profile>
       <members>
          <id>25</id>
          <name>Tetsu Inoue</name>
          <id>519207</id>
          <name>Uwe Schmidt</name>
       </members>
    </artist>
</artists>
```

Here's the Go code.  I'm wanting to get ALL of the ID fields in the MEMBERS section, but my code is only grabbing the last ID field where there may be none, one, or many.  How can I grab all IDs in the MEMBERS section into the MEMBERS array?

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

type Artists struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"artists"`
    Artist  []Artist `xml:"artist"`
}

type Artist struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"artist"`
    ArtistID uint32 `xml:" id,omitempty"`
    ArtistName string `xml:" name,omitempty"`
    Profile string `xml:" profile,omitempty"`
    RealName string `xml:" realname,omitempty"`
    Members MembersID `xml:"members,omitempty"`
}

type MembersID struct {
    MemberID uint32 `xml:"id,omitempty"`
}

func main() {

    xmlFile, err := os.Open("short_artists.xml")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Successfully opened artists file")
    defer xmlFile.Close()

    byteValue, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(xmlFile)
    var artists Artists
    xml.Unmarshal(byteValue, &artists)

    for i := 0; i < len(artists.Artist); i++ {
        fmt.Println("ArtistID: " + fmt.Sprint(artists.Artist[i].ArtistID))
        fmt.Println("Name: " + artists.Artist[i].ArtistName)
        fmt.Println("Real Name: " + artists.Artist[i].RealName)
        fmt.Println("Profile: " + artists.Artist[i].Profile)
        fmt.Println("")
        fmt.Printf("%v\n",artists.Artist[i].Members)
        fmt.Println("")
    }
}
```

All my Google and DuckDuckGo searches are purple.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: jeevatkm has the right solution, but I wanted to toss in another note - if you're reading in a 500MB XML file, you might consider streaming decoding using [`xml.Decoder`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Decoder) instead of reading the entire 500MB file into memory and then decoding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is `MembersID` struct definition. You have to use slice.

```
type MembersID struct {
    MemberID []uint32 `xml:"id,omitempty"`
}
```

Play link: https://play.golang.org/p/h4qTmSQoRg

Output:

```
ArtistID: 1
Name: The Persuader
Real Name: Jesper DahlbÃ¤ck
Profile: 

Members: []

ArtistID: 22
Name: DATacide
Real Name: 
Profile: Datacide began recording together in 1993, after Tetsu Inoue met Uwe Schmidt while vacationing near Frankfurt.


Members: [25 519207]
```

---

Bonus Tip:

Selectively fetching XML path values, if need be. For example getting all IDs of XML path `artist>members>id`

```
type MemberID struct {
    IDs []uint32 `xml:"artist>members>id"`
}
```

Play link: https://play.golang.org/p/sj7XPisgl7

Output:

```
[25 519207]
```

Comment: I knew I had to be missing something simple like that.  Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @ericbrow You're welcome. You can accept the answer.